# How to round off correctly with NET Math.Round(<decimal>,<int>,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

Tags: c#, .net, math, decimal, rounding

In .NET, why does `System.Math.Round(27.2351, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` yield `27.24` instead of `27.23`?

Third digit is 5 so we check for 4th digit that is 1 less than 5 so result should be 27.23

Is there any way to get this result.

**See My problem:**

I have amount 2013.86, and tax 7%. Now 7% of 2013.86 = 140.97

But this 2013.86 is my total amount.

details are like this:

```
Amount     Tax     Tax Value in 2 decimals by Math.Round
718.37      7%      50.29
496.06      7%      34.72
384.70      7%      26.93
310.93      7%      21.77
103.80      7%      7.27
----------------------------
2013.86             140.98
```

Total amount tax is 140.97 but inidividual's is 140.98 :(  :(
How to match total amount tax to summation of individual amount's tax.

Any Suggestion

Comment: Because the `5` in the 3rd decimal place causes it to round up. That's the correct behaviour. You're looking at the wrong decimal place - you don't check the `1`, you should check the `5`.

Comment: OK I will edit my post and explain my problem in detail.

Comment: Your error is because you are summing *rounded* numbers. This of course will produce a discrepancy. It has nothing to do with the method of rounding.

Comment: @Rob - he doesn't appear to be summing the rounded numbers. I think that's just part of the question. The maths is still wrong for the subtotal alone.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of rounding is incorrect. 27.2351 is closer to 27.24 than 27.23, and therefore rounding 27.2351 to 2 decimal places will *always* produce 27.24 regardless of any midpoint rounding option.

The midpoint rounding option only comes into play when a number is *exactly halfway* between the two choices, i.e. in your case 27.2350000. Consider the number line:

```
                                        /--What to do at this exact point?
                                        |  It's not "closer" to either side!
                                        |
                                        v
.............round to 27.230............|...........round to 27.240............
<~---------------------------------------------------------------------------~>
      |                                 |                                 |
    27.230                            27.235                            27.240
```

As for the behavior you're experiencing in your edit, this is normal. The sum of rounded numbers is not always going to be the same as if you sum the numbers first, then round once. You need to read up on how tax is supposed to be calculated for your particular jurisdiction, then follow that.

Comment: @vishal You avoid it by not summing rounded numbers. The 'total tax' possibly should be 7% of the total - not the sum of previous tax amounts - though it depends on how you are required to calculate and charge tax. Rounding like this will *always* have discrepancies, it is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

To start with the call to `System.Math.Round(27.2351, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` should return `27.24` as that's the correct answer to `2` decimal places.

You should also not use `double` for currency calculations - use `decimal` instead. Always suffix the number with an `m`, i.e. `27.2351m` rather than `27.2351` (which is a `double`).

Now, in the rest of your question you appear to be talking about getting the "ceiling", and not rounding.

The call `System.Math.Round(2013.86m * 0.07m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` gives you `140.97m`, but the tax should always go up to the nearest cent if there is a fractional amount of cents.

So this is the call you need:

```
System.Math.Ceiling(2013.86m * 0.07m * 100m) / 100m
```

That gives `140.98m`.

Comment: FWIW your statement about tax always rounding up is not always true around the world.

Comment: @lc. - Fair enough. Perhaps I should have said it **generally** goes up to the next whole cent. It seems in this case that that is what is needed.